# make express wait for firebase query before sending response

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying Firebase and i Joined two tables and want node js express  to send the response after the two query results are available

```
const database = firebase.database().ref();

const posts = database.child('posts');
const user = database.child('user');

let postWithName = [];
let postnames = []


function getUserNames(data) {
    if (data) {
        postnames = [] // NEW
        Object.values(data).forEach((value) => {
            user.child(value.user_id).once('value', sn => {
                let content = value.content;
                let date_posted = value.date_posted;
                let id = value.id;
                let title = value.title;
                let user_id = value.user_id;
                let user_Name = sn.val().name;
                postnames.push({
                    "id": id,
                    "title": title,
                    "date_posted": date_posted,
                    "content": content,
                    "user_Name": user_Name,
                    "user_id": user_id
                })
                postWithName = postnames.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return b.id - a.id;
                })
                console.log(postnames)
            })

        })
    }
}
function GetAll() {
    posts.once('value', snap => {
        postdata = snap.val()
        getUserNames(postdata)
    })

}

app.get('/getPosts', function (req, res) {
    GetAll()

    res.send({ "posts": postWithName })

})
```

the scheme is like this
User Table example:

```
8721da2c-0028-430f-a995-0d03c8abb393:{
  IsAdmin: 0,
  Password: 123456,
  email: 'admin@test.com',
  id: 1,
  image_file: 'https://i.imgur.com/fjYAIbl.png',
  name: 'Abdelrahman',
  phone: 1234567890,
  public_id: '8721da2c-0028-430f-a995-0d03c8abb393'
}
```

Post Table example :

```
6:{
    content: 'content 4',
    date_posted: '2021-01-06 08:54:44',
    id: 6,
    title: 'test 4',
    user_id: '8721da2c-0028-430f-a995-0d03c8abb393'
  },
```

when using the provided code, i don't get data at first get request, but after it i get the data as needed, i just need the request to wait for firebase query to finish and the list to be populated then send the response, how can it be done ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use async/await with your rest api services.
For more info you can check visit: Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: tried the async await but still it won't wait for the whole queries to have final values, if you tried it with firebase i'd appreciate an example using await and join queries

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution but you can use setTimeout function to delay the res.send for about two or three seconds until the queries are resolved.
make this your last solution as it'd affect the performance

Answer (score 0):

i think you can simply make simple if condition inside the foreach so that when the length of the res array is equal to the data array you'll send the response

```
 if (postWithName.length == data.length) {
                    res.send({ "posts": postWithName })
                }
```

i hope i helped